# Convert arbitrary output to json by column in the terminal?

Tags: json, linux, bash, command-line-interface

I'd like to be able to pipe the output from any command line program to a command that converts it to json.

For example my unknown program could accept target columns, a delimiter and output field names

```
# select columns 1 and 3 from the output and convert it to simple json
netstat -a | grep CLOSE_WAIT | convert_to_json 1,3 name,other
```

and would generate something like so:

```
[ 
  {"name": "tcp4", "other": "31"},
  {"name": "tcp4", "other": "0"} 
...
]
```

### I'm looking for something that works for any program, not just `netstat`!

#### I'm open to installing any 3rd party tool/opensource project, and tend to run things on linux/osx - does not have to be a bash script solution, can be written in node, perl, python, etc.

EDIT: I'm of course willing to pass in any more info that'd be required to make it work, for example a delimiter or multiple delimiters - I'd just like to avoid explicit parsing in the command line, and have the tool do that.

Comment: You will not be able to achieve a system that can convert "arbitrary" output to JSON. The reason being that it is not possible to write a parser that can parse arbitrary data. You will need to relax your constraints.

Comment: Maybe is your constraint was convert tabular data to JSON you might make some progress but you will need to tell your converter something about the format of the tabular data, such as the delimiter being used.

Comment: yeah i'm open to relaxing the constraints (ie having to pass more options into the `convert_to_json` script).... I'll add some clarification there...

Comment: You can use awk to do most of the work, but you have any code yet?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! - Nope - I don't have any code yet - I'm actually interested in seeing if solutions exist before I start trying to write one, as it feels like simple, yet probably more complex than expected and that someone else may have already built it (hopefully!)

Comment: https://github.com/clarkgrubb/data-tools

Comment: you'll need to pass so many "options" to your converter that you'll end up putting the same amount of effort to directly parse the output of your program. Of course a "jsonizer" can be made but it has to be program specific. A "jsonizer" program agnostic would require an input template in which you specify the actual output pattern of your program

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40384013/26510) seems to do a great job of having useable defaults, and allowing config... definitely useful, in my opinion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [a great list of tools](https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools) to work with command line output, and one of the tools listed is [sqawk](https://github.com/dbohdan/sqawk#convert-input-to-json-objects) which will convert any arbitrary data to json, and let you filter it using sql like queries!

#### Convert `ps` output to JSON

```
ps | sqawk -output json,indent=1 'select PID,TTY,TIME,CMD from a' trim=left header=1
```

#### Output

```
[{
    "PID"  : "3947",
    "TTY"  : "pts/2",
    "TIME" : "00:00:07",
    "CMD"  : "zsh"
},{
    "PID"  : "15951",
    "TTY"  : "pts/2",
    "TIME" : "00:00:00",
    "CMD"
}]
```

Answer (score 6):

### Filtering *STDIN* to build *json* variable

#### Introduction

As terminal is a very special kind of interface, with monospaced fonts,
tools are built to monitor on this terminal, many output could be very
difficult to parse:

`netstat` output is a good sample:

```
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13947569 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X1
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8760     /run/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     8790     /run/udev/control
```

Where some line contain blank fields, this could not be simply splitted on spaces.

Because of this, the requestet script `convert_to_json` will be posted at very bottom of this.

#### Simple space based splitting with `awk`

By using `awk`, you could use nice syntax:

```
netstat -an |
    awk '/CLOSE_WAIT/{
        printf "  { \42%s\42:\42%s\42,\42%s\42:\42%s\42},\n","name",$1,"other",$3
    }' |
    sed '1s/^/[\n/;$s/,$/\n]/'
```

#### Simple space based splitting with `perl`, but using json library

But this [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) way is more flexible:

```
netstat -an | perl -MJSON::XS -ne 'push @out,{"name"=>,$1,"other"=>$2} if /^(\S+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+)\s.*CLOSE_WAIT/;END{print encode_json(\@out)."\n";}'
```

or same but splitted;

```
netstat -an |
    perl -MJSON::XS -ne '
        push @out,{"name"=>,$1,"other"=>$2} if
                /^(\S+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+)\s.*CLOSE_WAIT/;
        END{print encode_json(\@out)."\n";
}'
```

Or *pretty-printed*:

```
netstat -an | perl -MJSON::XS -ne '
    push @out,{"name"=>,$1,"other"=>$2} if /^(\S+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+)\s.*CLOSE_WAIT/;
    END{$coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;
        print $coder->encode(\@out);}'
```

Finally, I like this version not based on [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
netstat -an | perl -MJSON::XS -ne '
    do {
        my @line=split(/\s+/);
        push @out,{"name"=>,$line[0],"other"=>$line[2]}
    } if /CLOSE_WAIT/;
    END{
        $coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;
        print $coder->encode(\@out);
    }'
```

But you could run command inside perl script:

```
perl -MJSON::XS -e '
    open STDIN,"netstat -an|";
    my @out;
    while (<>){
        push @out,{"name"=>,$1,"other"=>$2} if /^(\S+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+)\s.*CLOSE_WAIT/;
    };
    print encode_json \@out;'
```

This could become a basical prototyp:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use JSON::XS;
my $coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;

$ENV{'LANG'}='C';
open STDIN,"netstat -naut|";
my @out;
my @fields;

my $searchre=":";
$searchre = shift @ARGV if @ARGV;

while (<>){
    map { s/_/ /g;push @fields,$_; } split(/\s+/) if
        /^Proto.*State/ && s/\sAddr/_Addr/g;
    do {
        my @line=split(/\s+/);
        my %entry;
        for my $i (0..$#fields) {
            $entry{$fields[$i]}=$line[$i];
        };
        push @out,\%entry;
    } if /$searchre/;
}

print $coder->encode(\@out);
```

(Without argument, this will dump entire `netstat -uta`, but you could give any search string as argument, like *CLOSE* or an IP.)

#### Positional parameters, `netstat2json.pl`

This method could work with many other tools than `netcat`, with some
corrections:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use JSON::XS;
my $coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;
$ENV{'LANG'}='C';
open STDIN,"netstat -nap|";
my ( $searchre ,@out,%fields)=( "[/:]" );
$searchre = shift @ARGV if @ARGV;
while (<>){
    next if /^Active\s.*\)$/;
    /^Proto.*State/ && do {
        s/\s(name|Addr)/_$1/g;
        my @head;
        map { s/_/ /g;push @head,$_; } split(/\s+/);
        s/_/ /g;
        %fields=();
        for my $i (0..$#head) {
            my $crt=index($_,$head[$i]);
            my $next=-1;
            $next=index($_,$head[$i+1])-$crt-1 if $i < $#head;
            $fields{$head[$i]}=[$crt,$next];
        }
        next;
    };
    do {
        my $line=$_;
        my %entry;
        for my $i (keys %fields) {
            my $crt=substr($line,$fields{$i}[0],$fields{$i}[1]);
            $crt=~s/^\s*(\S(|.*\S))\s*$/$1/;
            $entry{$i}=$crt;
        };
        push @out,\%entry;
    } if /$searchre/;
}
print $coder->encode(\@out);
```

- find header lines *`Proto.*State`* (specific to `netcat`)
- store fieldnames with position and length
- split line by field length,then trim spaces
- dump variable as json string.

This could be run with arguments, like previously:

```
./netstat2json.pl CLOS
[
   {
      "Local Address" : "127.0.0.1:31001",
      "State" : "CLOSE_WAIT",
      "Recv-Q" : "18",
      "Proto" : "tcp",
      "Send-Q" : "0",
      "Foreign Address" : "127.0.0.1:55938",
      "PID/Program name" : "-"
   },
   {
      "Recv-Q" : "1",
      "Local Address" : "::1:53816",
      "State" : "CLOSE_WAIT",
      "Send-Q" : "0",
      "PID/Program name" : "-",
      "Foreign Address" : "::1:631",
      "Proto" : "tcp6"
   }
]
```

And empty fields don't break variable assignement:

```
./netstat2json.pl 1000.*systemd/notify
[
   {
      "Proto" : "unix",
      "I-Node" : "33378",
      "RefCnt" : "2",
      "Path" : "/run/user/1000/systemd/notify",
      "PID/Program name" : "-",
      "Type" : "DGRAM",
      "Flags" : "[ ]",
      "State" : ""
   }
]
```

***Nota!*** This modified version run `netstat` with `-nap` arguments to get *`PID/Program name`* field.

If not run by superuser *`root`*, you could become this output on *`STDERR`*:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

You could avoid them

- by running  `netstat2json.pl 2>/dev/null`,
- by running this as *`root`* or with `sudo` or
- edit line `#6`, change `"netstat -nap|"` for  `"netstat -na|"`.

#### `convert_to_json.pl` [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script to transform *STDIN* to json.

There is the `convert_to_json.pl` perl script, strictly as requested: to be run as `netstat -an | grep CLOSE | ./convert_to_json.pl 1,3 name,other`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use JSON::XS;
my $coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref;

my (@fields,@pos,@out);

map {
    push @pos,1*$_-1
} split ",",shift @ARGV;      

map { 
    push @fields,$_
} split ",",shift @ARGV;

die "Number of fields don't match number of positions" if $#fields ne $#pos;

while (<>) {
    my @line=split(/\s+/);
    my %entry;
    for my $i (0..$#fields) {
         $entry{$fields[$i]}=$line[$pos[$i]];
    };
    push @out,\%entry;
}
print $coder->encode(\@out);
```

Comment: Great idea! Perl's JSON module is perfect for this. I think if you took the `netstat` stuff out (so just reading `stdin`) and parameterised the column numbers and names, it would be just what OP wants.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ok, answer edited: added filter way as strictly, and a more elabored, *ready to run* perl script.

Comment: Thanks for the work - so I don't know perl - can you reformat this so it can work like I give in my example? It seems super close - ie how to make it work roughly like this: `netstat -a | grep CLOSE_WAIT | convert_to_json 1,3 name,other`

Comment: @BradParks I do the `grep` inside perl script. There is some different approach depending on if you prefer to use *regex* or *split*. As your question stand for *columns*, I think the *version not based on regex* is what you're searching for: `netstat -an | perl -MJSON::XS -ne 'do { my @line=split(/\s+/); push @out,{"name"=>,$line[0],"other"=>$line[2]} } if /CLOSE_WAIT/; END{ $coder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref; print $coder->encode(\@out); }' `

Answer (score 5):

Here's my ruby version :

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
#
# Converts stdin columns to a JSON array of hashes
#
# Installation : Save as convert_to_json, make it executable and put it somewhere in PATH. Ruby must be installed
#
# Examples :
#
# netstat -a | grep CLOSE_WAIT | convert_to_json 1,3 name,other
# ls -l | convert_to_json
# ls -l | convert_to_json 6,7,8,9
# ls -l | convert_to_json 6,7,8,9 month,day,time,name
# convert_to_json 1,2 time,value ";" < some_file.csv
#
#
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246134/convert-arbitrary-output-to-json-by-column-in-the-terminal

require 'json'

script_name = File.basename(__FILE__)
syntax = "Syntax : command_which_outputs_columns | #{script_name} column1_id,column2_id,...,columnN_id column1_name,column2_name,...,columnN_name delimiter"


if $stdin.tty? or $stdin.closed? then
  $stderr.puts syntax
else
  if ARGV[2]
    delimiter = ARGV[2]
    $stderr.puts "#{script_name} : Using #{delimiter} as delimiter"
  else
    delimiter = /\s+/
  end

  column_ids = (ARGV[0] || "").split(',').map{|column_id| column_id.to_i-1}
  column_names = (ARGV[1] || "").split(',')

  results = []
  $stdin.each do |stdin_line|
    if column_ids.empty?
      values = stdin_line.strip.split(delimiter)
    else
      values = stdin_line.strip.split(delimiter).values_at(*column_ids)
    end
    line_hash=Hash.new
    values.each_with_index.each{|value,i|
      colum_name = column_names[i] || "column#{(column_ids[i] || i)+1}"
      line_hash[colum_name]=value
    }
    results<<line_hash
  end
  puts JSON.pretty_generate(results)
end
```

It works as defined in your example :

```
netstat -a | grep CLOSE_WAIT | convert_to_json 1,3 name,other
[
  {
    "name": "tcp",
    "other": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "tcp6",
    "other": "0"
  }
]
```

As a bonus, you can

- omit to specify parameters : every column will be converted to json
- omit to specify names : column will be called column1, column2, ...
- choose a missing column : value will be null
- define a delimiter as third parameter. Default is whitespace

Other examples :

```
netstat -a | grep CLOSE_WAIT | ./convert_to_json
# [
#   {
#     "column1": "tcp",
#     "column2": "1",
#     "column3": "0",
#     "column4": "10.0.2.15:51074",
#     "column5": "123.45.101.207:https",
#     "column6": "CLOSE_WAIT"
#   },
#   {
#     "column1": "tcp6",
#     "column2": "1",
#     "column3": "0",
#     "column4": "ip6-localhost:50293",
#     "column5": "ip6-localhost:ipp",
#     "column6": "CLOSE_WAIT"
#   }
# ]

netstat -a | grep CLOSE_WAIT | ./convert_to_json 1,3
# [
#   {
#     "column1": "tcp",
#     "column3": "0"
#   },
#   {
#     "column1": "tcp6",
#     "column3": "0"
#   }
# ]

ls -l | tail -n3 | convert_to_json 6,7,8,9 month,day,time,name
# [
#   {
#     "month": "Oct",
#     "day": "27",
#     "time": "10:35",
#     "name": "test.dot"
#   },
#   {
#     "month": "Nov",
#     "day": "2",
#     "time": "14:27",
#     "name": "uniq.rb"
#   },
#   {
#     "month": "Nov",
#     "day": "2",
#     "time": "14:27",
#     "name": "utf8_nokogiri.rb"
#   }
# ]

# NOTE: ls -l uses the 8th column for year, not time, for older files :
ls --full-time -t /usr/share/doc | tail -n3 | ./convert_to_json 6,7,9 yyyymmdd,time,name
[
  {
    "yyyymmdd": "2013-10-21",
    "time": "15:15:20.000000000",
    "name": "libbz2-dev"
  },
  {
    "yyyymmdd": "2013-10-10",
    "time": "16:27:32.000000000",
    "name": "zsh"
  },
  {
    "yyyymmdd": "2013-10-03",
    "time": "18:52:45.000000000",
    "name": "manpages-dev"
  }
]

ls -l | tail -n3 | convert_to_json 9,12
# [
#   {
#     "column9": "test.dot",
#     "column12": null
#   },
#   {
#     "column9": "uniq.rb",
#     "column12": null
#   },
#   {
#     "column9": "utf8_nokogiri.rb",
#     "column12": null
#   }
# ]

convert_to_json 1,2 time,value ";" < some_file.csv
# convert_to_json : Using ; as delimiter
# [
#   {
#     "time": "1",
#     "value": "3"
#   },
#   {
#     "time": "2",
#     "value": "5"
#   }
# ]
```

Comment: This is wrong: `ls /usr/share/doc -lt | tail -n5 |  ./convert2json.rb 6,7,8,9 month,day,time,name` give: `"time": "2013"`!! Have a look at introduction of my answer!

Comment: You're right, `ls -l` outputs year in the 8th column for older files, and I didn't think about it. I'll add an example with `ls --full-time`.

Answer (score 3):

Just a really basic concept for an approach that is not at all rigorous or fully-featured but which might give you an idea how to do the bulk of this with `awk`, since you don't seem to have much yet!

```
netstat -a | grep CLOSE_WAIT | awk 'BEGIN{print "["} {print "  {\"name\": \"",$1,"\", \"other\": \"",$2,"\"}"} END{print "]"}' OFS=""
[
  {"name": "tcp4", "other": "31"}
  {"name": "tcp4", "other": "31"}
  {"name": "tcp4", "other": "31"}
  {"name": "tcp4", "other": "31"}
  {"name": "tcp4", "other": "0"}
  {"name": "tcp4", "other": "31"}
]
```

I know it doesn't do the commas at the line-ends, and I know it doesn't take parameters - but both of those are solvable.

One idea for parameters would be to pass them to `awk` like this:

```
awk -v fields="1:4:7" -v headings="name:other:fred" '{...}'
```

then `split()` those in the `BEGIN` section and iterate through them in the main loop. That would look something like this:

```
echo hi | awk -v fields="1:3:5" -v headings="HeadA:HeadB:HeadC" 'BEGIN{split(headings,h,":"); split(fields,f,":")} {for(i in h)print h[i],f[i];}'

HeadA 1
HeadB 3
HeadC 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - though I'm hoping to find a more general solution - not something where I have to parse each different command. So an awk script that wrapped up this process would be great, but i don't want to pipe to awk, I want to pipe to some program that wraps up all the parsing... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here it is my python version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import re

def all_columns_to_json (column_dict, columns_line):    
    json_object = {}    

    for column_index, column_value in enumerate(columns_line):
        if column_index in column_dict:
            column_name = column_dict[column_index]
        else:
            column_name = str(column_index)

        json_object[column_name] = column_value

    return json_object


def filter_columns_in_dict_to_json(column_dict, columns_line):
    '''Parse columns_line, make sure every element in column_dict
       exists there, filter elements that are not in column_dict from 
       columns_line, and convert it to a dict.
    '''
    json_object = {}    

    for column_index, column_name in column_dict.items():
        try:
            json_object[column_name] = columns_line[column_index]
        except IndexError as err:
            # columns_line doesn't has column_index.

            raise ValueError('Invalid table line ({}) : no {} element.'.format(columns_line,
                                                                               column_index)) from err     

    return json_object

def columns_line_to_json (column_dict, columns_line, should_filter_colunms):
    '''Parse a list of values to a json object with special names.
    '''

    if should_filter_colunms:
        return filter_columns_in_dict_to_json(column_dict, columns_line)
    else:
        return all_columns_to_json(column_dict, columns_line)

def regex_from_delims_list(delims_list):
    '''Get a regex compiled pattern from a delims list'''    

    one_characters_delims = ''
    final_pattern = ''

    for delim in delims_list:
        delim_and_maybe_min_max = delim.split(':')

        escaped_delim = re.escape(delim_and_maybe_min_max[0])

        # Check if this is a delim without min count.
        if len(delim) == 1:
            final_pattern += "%s{1,}|" % (escaped_delim)
        elif len(delim) == 2:
            min_and_maybe_max = delim_and_maybe_min_max[1].split('-')

            current_pattern = escaped_delim

            # Add count to the regex (only min or max too)
            if len(min_and_maybe_max) == 2:
                current_pattern += '{%d,%d}' % (int(min_and_maybe_max[0],
                                                int(min_and_maybe_max[1])))
            else:
                current_pattern += '{%d,}' % (int(min_and_maybe_max[0]))

            final_pattern += current_pattern + '|'
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid ':' count in the delimiter argument")

        # If there are one character delims without count, add them. If not
        # Remove the last OR ('|').

        final_pattern = final_pattern[:-1]

        return re.compile (final_pattern)


def main(args):
    column_dict = {}    

    # Split the user's argument by a comma, and parse each columns
    # seperatly.
    for column_and_name in args.columns_and_names.split(','):
        # Split the name from the columns.
        column_and_name = column_and_name.split('=')
        if len(column_and_name) > 2:
            raise ValueError("Invalid column: {}".format(str(column_and_name())))

        # If there is not name, set it to the column index.
        if len(column_and_name) == 1:
            column_and_name.append (str(column_and_name[0]))

        # Try to convert the column index is it isn't '*'
        if column_and_name[0] != '*':
            try:
                column_and_name[0] = int(column_and_name[0])
            except ValueError as err:
                raise ValueError('Invalid column index: {} (not an integer)'.format(column_and_name[0])) from err

        # Add this column definition. 
        column_dict[column_and_name[0]] = column_and_name[1]


    # Check if column_dict has the '*' member.
    # If it does, we will print all of the columns (even ones that
    # are not in column_dict)
    should_filter_colunms = ('*' not in column_dict)

    # We have checked it, no need for it now.
    if not should_filter_colunms:
        del column_dict['*']

    # Parse the delim list into a regex pattern.
    strip_regex_pattern = regex_from_delims_list(args.delimiters)

    json_objects_list = []    

    for fd in args.infiles:
        for line in fd:
            # Convert bytes object to string.
            if isinstance(line, bytes): 
                line = line.decode('utf-8')

            # Strip the \n in the end of the line.
            line = line.rstrip('\n')            

            # Split the line by the delims.
            splitted_line = re.split(strip_regex_pattern, line)

            json_objects_list.append (columns_line_to_json (column_dict, splitted_line, should_filter_colunms))

    print(json.dumps (json_objects_list))


def comma_list(string):
    '''Convert a comma list '1,2,3,4' to a list
    [1,2,3,4] with escaping of , by a one \\ char'''

    # Split the string by commas after non-\ chars.
    splitted_string = re.split('(?!\\\).,', re.escape(string))

    replaced_string = []    

    # Replace '\,' with ',' and '\\' with '\'.
    for string in splitted_string:
        string = string.replace ('\\\\', '\\')
        string = string.replace ('\\\\,', ',')

        replaced_string.append (string)    

    return replaced_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse    
    from sys import stdin

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('columns_and_names', help='The columns and its names to print out (format: n=name)', default='*')
    parser.add_argument('--delim', '-d', type=comma_list, 
                        help='A list of input columns delimiters. Format: delim[:min[-max]]. Where `min` and `max` are the numbers of times `delim` should repeat. As default min=1 and max is not set. Enter "\," for the delimiter "," and "\\\\"" for "\\"',
                        default=(' ', '\t'), 
                        metavar='delim[:min-max]')
    parser.add_argument('infiles', type=argparse.FileType('rb'), default=(stdin,), metavar='file', nargs='*')

    main(parser.parse_args())
```

(See https://github.com/Reflexe/convert_table_to_json for more usage examples)

I tried to look for a similar program, but I could not find anything so I had to write it (I think it is a very useful tool).

For example, to use it with netstat, use this:

```
$ netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED |  ./convert_to_json.py  '2=name,3=other'
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14129428)

Comment: @RamenChef It is a tool that does exactly what the question wanted.

Comment: Well, no, it is just a link to a tool. See, for example, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Probably, BASH is not the best platform for it. However, I provide a half-baked solution with some trick you will need.

```
#!/bin/bash

function procline {
    IFS=' ' list=($1)
    echo -n "{ first_column: \"" ${list[0]} "\","
    echo "{ second_column: \"" ${list[1]} "\" }},"
}

tr -s " " | eval \
    'while IFS= read -r line; do procline "$line"; done'
```

Some explanation:

- `tr` truncates the spaces
- `while IFS`... passes the result line-by-line to `procline` function
- `procline` function first splits the line, then creates kinda JSON.

My opinion is, that the output of the `tr` should be passed to another script written in other language, e.g. Python, PHP-CLI etc., if not the whole. It looks pretty easy-to-process:

```
tcp4 0 0 192.168.99.1.56358 192.168.99.100.32111 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp4 31 0 192.168.100.179.56129 server-54-192-20.https CLOSE_WAIT
```